# in Azure, how to list all the subscriptions under a management group by using Python SDK?

Tags: azure, azure-python-sdk, azure-subscription, azure-management-groups

I am trying to list all the **Azure** subscriptions under a specific management group by using **Azure Python SDK**. But I couldn't find any function which retrieves them.

Do you have any idea?

Comment: Can you please provide any code which you have tried?

Answer (score 0):

For this kind of thing you should you [Azure Resource Graph](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/governance/resource-graph/overview), which is simply

> Azure Resource Graph is an Azure service designed to extend Azure Resource Management by providing efficient and performant resource exploration with the ability to query at scale across a given set of subscriptions so that you can effectively govern your environment.

There's also an REST API on place to be consumed by various SDKs including [Python](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/governance/resource-graph/first-query-python)

Hope it will helps :)

Answer (score 0):

```
from azure.mgmt.subscription import SubscriptionClient

credential = DefaultAzureCredential()    
subscription_client = SubscriptionClient(credential)
subscription_list = subscription_client.subscriptions.list()
result = [item for item in subscription_list]
for item in result:
    print("The subscription that will be checked: ", item.display_name)
```

With the `SubscriptionClient` class, I have achieved to list the subscriptions that an account has access.